# Can I calculate the standard error of all columns with the "summarise_all" function in R dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am preparing course material for the dplyr in R. 
Assuming that our data set is "iris" someone can calculate the mean and sd of all columns with the summarise all function

```
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise_all(funs(mean, sd), na.rm=TRUE)
```

Howeveer when I am trying to calulate the standard error I am taking an error message.

```
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise_all(funs(mean, sd, se = sd/sqrt(n)), na.rm=TRUE)
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use :

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise_all(list(mean = ~mean(.), sd = ~sd(.), se = ~sd(./sqrt(.))))
```

Or probably shorter but doesn't give you the column names you desire :

```
iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise_all(list(mean, sd, se = ~sd(./sqrt(.))))
```

Comment: Thank you, Ronak! What does the dot in (.) signify, and what does the "~."

Comment: `~` is formula-style syntax to apply functions (It is an alternative to anonymous functions) and `.` here signifies column values in each group.

Comment: alternatively in upcoming dplyr 1.0.0:  iris %>%  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(across(.fns = list(mean = mean, sd = sd, se = ~sd(./sqrt(.)))))

Answer (score 3):

For anyone stumbling across this, I'm fairly sure the other comments are  miscalculating the SE as sd/sqrt instead of the sd/(sqrt of the sample size). I don't have the reputation to reply to those, but substituting

`se = ~sd(.x)/sqrt(length(.x))`

into the above formulas should work.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `summarise` with `across` in the new releas

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>%
     group_by(Species) %>%
    summarise(across(everything(), list(mean = mean, sd = sd, se = ~sd(.)/sqrt(.))))
```

Comment: @einar I didn't see it when I posted.  It is better to post as an answer instead of comments because people don't usually reead all the comments. thanks